# Передать переменную из метода в класс

Tags: java, android

Допустим, так. Нужно получить переменную `s` из метода `onClick`. Для дальнейшей с ней работы в основном классе. Как это сделать?

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

...

public void onClick(View v) {
    String s = editText.getText().toString();    
}

...

String t = s;
```

Comment: Нужно сделать ее переменной класса.

Answer (score 2):

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

String t = "";
...

public void onClick(View v) {
    String s = editText.getText().toString();    
    // присваиваем значение 's' переменной класса 't'
    this.t = s;
}

...

// String t = s;  -
```

Comment: в Java традиционно служебное поле `this` в данном случае можно (и нужно) не использовать, так как​ нет одноименных полей класса и локальных переменных в присваивании.

Comment: @pavlofff Вы правы, что это все бессмысленно, да и сама идея менять состояние объекта в onClick выглядит подозрительной. Я просто ответил на вопрос, без нравоучений. Я думаю вы моглибы ответить тоже и объяснить про области видимости, наименование переменных итд.

Comment: об этом уже объяснили много раз и на этом ресурсе и в любой книжке по программированию на Java  и повторятся в очередной раз нет никакого желания :)

Comment: @pavlofff  насчет использования 'this' в Java, за исключением случаев где это необходимо, это вопрос стиля.